How to create WinUI3 GUI in PowerShell?
The Goal
Creating and rendering a simple WinUI3 GUI in PowerShell 7.5 which is based on .NET 9. Nothing complicated, just a window and a button in it, such as this XAML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="App1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>



Using, importing or defining C# code in PowerShell is totally okay too for the solution.
The only thing I don't want to do is to build/compile binaries of my own such as executables or DLLs. I want to use .cs CSharp files uncompiled in PowerShell if there is a need for CSharp code.
Loading and using Microsoft-signed DLLs is completely okay.

What I've tried so far
I've created a fully working WinUI3 app in Visual Studio 2022 using the latest WindowsApps SDK. Then inside of the Winui3 project\App1\bin\x64\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0\win-x64 folder I've tried loading all of the DLLs in there in PowerShell. Some 200 dlls loaded and a few failed to load.
In PowerShell now I have access to the type [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window] but when I try to create an instance of it
New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window
# Or
[Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window]::new()

I get the following error
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "The type initializer for '_IWindowFactory' threw an exception."

It looks like there is a dependency missing for _IWindowFactory.

This is the full error message

Exception             : 
    Type           : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException
    ErrorRecord    : 
        Exception             : 
            Type    : System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException
            Message : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "The type initializer for '_IWindowFactory' threw an exception."
            HResult : -2146233087
        CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
        FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeInitializationException
        InvocationInfo        : 
            ScriptLineNumber : 1
            OffsetInLine     : 1
            HistoryId        : 4
            Line             : [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window]::new()
            Statement        : [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window]::new()
            PositionMessage  : At line:1 char:1
                               + [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window]::new()
                               + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            CommandOrigin    : Internal
        ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
    TargetSite     : 
        Name          : ConvertToMethodInvocationException
        DeclaringType : [System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps]
        MemberType    : Method
        Module        : System.Management.Automation.dll
    Message        : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "The type initializer for '_IWindowFactory' threw an exception."
    Data           : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
    InnerException : 
        Type           : System.TypeInitializationException
        TypeName       : _IWindowFactory
        TargetSite     : 
            Name          : get_Instance
            DeclaringType : [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window+_IWindowFactory]
            MemberType    : Method
            Module        : Microsoft.WinUI.dll
        Message        : The type initializer for '_IWindowFactory' threw an exception.
        InnerException : 
            Type           : System.TypeInitializationException
            TypeName       : WinRT.ActivationFactory`1
            TargetSite     : 
                Name          : As
                DeclaringType : [WinRT.ActivationFactory`1[T]]
                MemberType    : Method
                Module        : Microsoft.WinUI.dll
            Message        : The type initializer for 'WinRT.ActivationFactory`1' threw an exception.
            InnerException : 
                Type       : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
                ErrorCode  : -2147221164
                TargetSite : 
                    Name          : ThrowExceptionForHR
                    DeclaringType : [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]
                    MemberType    : Method
                    Module        : System.Private.CoreLib.dll
                Message    : Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
                Source     : System.Private.CoreLib
                HResult    : -2147221164
                StackTrace : 
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at WinRT.BaseActivationFactory..ctor(String typeNamespace, String typeFullName)
   at WinRT.ActivationFactory`1..ctor()
   at WinRT.ActivationFactory`1..cctor()
            Source         : Microsoft.WinUI
            HResult        : -2146233036
            StackTrace     : 
   at WinRT.ActivationFactory`1.As(Guid iid)
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window._IWindowFactory..ctor()
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window._IWindowFactory..cctor()
        Source         : Microsoft.WinUI
        HResult        : -2146233036
        StackTrace     : 
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window._IWindowFactory.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window..ctor()
   at CallSite.Target(Closure, CallSite, Type)
    Source         : System.Management.Automation
    HResult        : -2146233087
    StackTrace     : 
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.ConvertToMethodInvocationException(Exception exception, Type typeToThrow, String methodName, Int32 numArgs, MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure, CallSite, Type)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeInitializationException
InvocationInfo        : 
    ScriptLineNumber : 1
    OffsetInLine     : 1
    HistoryId        : 4
    Line             : [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window]::new()
    Statement        : [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window]::new()
    PositionMessage  : At line:1 char:1
                       + [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window]::new()
                       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CommandOrigin    : Internal
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1



Other people have tried this too and had similar results. Another issue related to this problem asking for some guidance from Microsoft.
I don't know how Visual Studio does this that makes it all so easy and automated, but I believe I need to do the same tasks manually in PowerShell.

There is a python translation here which could be helpful.

After we looked into the stacktrace for this error we found that this is due to root cause of add-type -Path System.Private.CoreLib.dll not loading. Even if we use 7.4.2(release) or 7.5(preview) of PowerShell which should work with .Net 8 according to other stack exchanges. New error: "Add-Type: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0," This is the root cause.

Do you want "pure" powershell or is it ok to use embedded C# (Add-Type -Language CSharp etc.)

@SimonMourier it is TOTALLY okay to embed C# code as well, my only goal is to create WinUI3 GUI in PowerShell, whatever it takes.

The XAML part is the most complex since one must create XBF files (compiled XAML binary), .PRI files (list of resources) etc. You can do w/o XAML (all in code) or load an external WinUI3 component (which would be developped with Visual Studio with XAML in C# or another language). What do you prefer?

All in code is good really, but i also like to know the other method you are suggesting if possible. What matters the most to me is not to build/generate binaries. If there is a need for C#, i want to directly use it inside of PowerShell with Add-Type, however it's okay if I need to load or use Microsoft-signed binaries or dlls.

Simon provided a fantastic answer. I tried to convert his answer to an all powershell solution. The only part I couldn't figure out was why this line can't be translated one for one. $this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add([Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.XamlControlsResources]::new())
This builds the application in another runspace while leaving room to add to the DataContext and to call Window.Activate() when needed by dispatcherqueue.
# cd 'C:\change\this'
Add-Type -Path ".\WinRT.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.Net.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.InteractiveExperiences.Projection.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.WinUI.dll"

# //Setup runspacepool and shared variable
$ConcurrentDict = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary[string,object]]::new()
$State = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault()
$RunspaceVariable = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateVariableEntry]::new('ConcurrentDict', $ConcurrentDict, $null)
$State.Variables.Add($RunspaceVariable)
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $([int]$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS + 1), $State, (Get-Host))
$RunspacePool.Open()
$Powershell = [PowerShell]::Create()
$Powershell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

$AppSetup = @'
# cd 'C:\change\this'
Add-Type -Path ".\WinRT.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.Net.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.InteractiveExperiences.Projection.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.WinUI.dll"

class PwshWinUIApp : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.IXamlMetadataProvider {
    # //App is able to load without Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.IXamlMetadataProvider but interaction such as clicking a button will crash the terminal without it.

    $MainWindow
    $provider = [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.XamlTypeInfo.XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider]::new()
    static [bool]$OkWasClicked
    $SharedConcurrentDictionary

    [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.IXamlType]GetXamlType([type]$type) {
        return $this.provider.GetXamlType($type)
    }
    [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.IXamlType]GetXamlType([string]$fullname) {
        return $this.provider.GetXamlType($fullname)
    }
    [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XmlnsDefinition[]]GetXmlnsDefinitions() {
        return $this.provider.GetXmlnsDefinitions()
    }

    PwshWinUIApp() {}
    PwshWinUIApp($SharedConcurrentDictionary) {
        $this.SharedConcurrentDictionary = $SharedConcurrentDictionary
    }
    OnLaunched([Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs]$a) {
        if ($null -ne $this.MainWindow) { return }

        # //Don't know why this line is problematic or how to get it to work in powershell. But the app works without it.
        # $this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add([Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.XamlControlsResources]::new())
        
        $xaml = '<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
                <StackPanel
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding tbContent, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="10" />
                    <Button x:Name="okButton" Margin="10">OK</Button>
                    <Button x:Name="cancelButton" Margin="10">Cancel</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Window>'

        $this.MainWindow = [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xaml)

        $ClassScope = $this
        $WindowScope = $this.MainWindow
        
        $this.SharedConcurrentDictionary.App = $ClassScope # Terminal will crash on most properties and the object itself when printing to terminal.
        $this.SharedConcurrentDictionary.Window = $WindowScope
        $this.SharedConcurrentDictionary.Dispatcher = $WindowScope.DispatcherQueue

        $this.SharedConcurrentDictionary.OnloadFinished = $true
        # $this.MainWindow.Activate()
    }
    static [bool] Run($SharedConcurrentDictionary) {
        [Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.DynamicDependency.Bootstrap]::Initialize(0x0010005)

        [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application]::Start({
            [PwshWinUIApp]::new($SharedConcurrentDictionary)
        })
        [Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.DynamicDependency.Bootstrap]::Shutdown()
        return [PwshWinUIApp]::OkWasClicked
    }
}

[PwshWinUIApp]::Run($ConcurrentDict)
'@

# //Start app without window
$AppSetupScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($AppSetup)
$null = $Powershell.AddScript($AppSetupScriptBlock)
$Handle = $Powershell.BeginInvoke()

# //Optional binding to class
[NoRunspaceAffinity()]
class binder {
    # //Should inherit IPropertyNotifyChanged
    # //or a dependency object
    binder(){}
    $tbContent = 'Without IPropertyNotifyChanged, this will not update'
}
$ConcurrentDict.binder = [binder]::new()

# //Wait for app to finish loading
while ($ConcurrentDict.OnloadFinished -ne $true) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
}

# //Send actions to dispatcher such as setting up buttons (Could also bind buttons through a class like above)
$null = $ConcurrentDict.Dispatcher.TryEnqueue([scriptblock]::create({
    # //This is inside the Window thread/runspace
    # //Because ConcurrentDict is a shared variable, the Window thread can also access it
    # //We have less access compared to wpf, where you could traverse the wpf object on any thread.
    # //If you call $ConcurrentDict.Window.Content outside of this thread, it will be empty.

    $sp = $ConcurrentDict.Window.Content
    $ConcurrentDict.Window.Content.DataContext = $ConcurrentDict.binder

    $ok = $sp.FindName("okButton")
    $cancel = $sp.FindName("cancelButton")
    
    $ok.add_Click([scriptblock]::create({
        param($s, $e)
        Write-Verbose "sender is: $($s.Name)" -Verbose
        
        [PwshWinUIApp]::OkWasClicked = $true
        
        $ConcurrentDict.ThreadId = "Set from Thread Id: $([System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)"
        $ConcurrentDict.Window.Close()
    }.ToString()))
    
    $cancel.add_Click([scriptblock]::create({
        param($s, $e)
        Write-Verbose "sender is: $($s.Name)" -Verbose
        
        $ConcurrentDict.ThreadId = "Set from Thread Id: $([System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)"
        $ConcurrentDict.Window.Close()
    }.ToString()))
}.ToString()))

# //Finally show the window via dispatcher
$Action = {$ConcurrentDict.Window.Activate()}.ToString()
$NoContextAction = [scriptblock]::create($Action)
$null = $ConcurrentDict.Window.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue($NoContextAction)

"Current Thread Id: $([System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)"
$ConcurrentDict


I feel like I just found something I’ve been searching for over 3 years for. Thank you!

2 questions - First is if I want to add a XAML element (such as NavigationView) how can I go about doing that? I seem to get an error (but I can add things like a ToggleButton so I think its a missing namespace?)
2nd - I notice that the visual elements are slightly different than the C# example, i.e. square instead of rounded, etc. Any idea why this might be?

The visual elements are different because it's defaulting to uwp style. The powershell equvalent of this Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new XamlControlsResources()); does not work as I commented it out and that looks like it sets the  default winui3 style.

This is a way better answer because you can actually assign objects and still use PowerShell to cross reference info. Far better answer.

What specifically is bypassing System.Private.CoreLib in this? It is strange because according to the stacktrace, that is what was required. Something must be fixing this in a roundabout way. Do you know exactly what it is? I'd like to know how specifically this is being done. in Answer #1 -CompilerOptions /nowarn:CS1701 is used, but you aren't even using that?

I added these to $AppSetup in case any weirdness happens with IO/threading issues:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.InteropServices
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Threading

Starting a WinUI3 app is quite involved, and supporting full XAML is another difficulty as it also requires compiled XAML files (.xbf), resource files (.pri), etc. These can be built with SDK tools but here I will just demonstrate how to start a WinUI .NET 8 application based on PowerShell 7.4 with or without simple XAML (no automatic binding), without the need for Visual Studio, with zero compilation at deployment time.
First create a directory and put in there:

The following .ps1 file,
The content of the latest Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK package nuget, only the lib\net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0 directory (as of today, it's not targeting .NET 8),
Add to that WinRT.Runtime.dll from the Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT nuget
Add to that Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll from the Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref nuget
Add to that Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.dll from WinAppSDK Runtime (you can find it in a place like C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.5_5001.95.533.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe as of today). Note: obviously, the Windows App Runtime must be installed on the PC for all this to work.
Optionaly put a .ico file if you want nice icons for your windows

This is how your folder should look (you can delete the .xml files they are for SDK documentation):

Now here is the content of BasicWinUI.ps1 (as you can see it's 95% C#)
Add-Type -Path ".\WinRT.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.Net.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.InteractiveExperiences.Projection.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.WinUI.dll"

$referencedAssemblies = @(
    "System.Threading" # for SynchronizationContext
    ".\WinRT.Runtime.dll"
    ".\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll"
    ".\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.Net.dll"
    ".\Microsoft.InteractiveExperiences.Projection.dll"
    ".\Microsoft.WinUI.dll"
)

#Note: we remove warning CS1701: Assuming assembly reference 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
#  used by 'Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.Net'
#  matches identity 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' of 'System.Runtime',
#  you may need to supply runtime policy
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $referencedAssemblies -CompilerOptions /nowarn:CS1701 -Language CSharp @"
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.UI.Dispatching;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.XamlTypeInfo;
using Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.DynamicDependency;
using Windows.Graphics;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using WinRT.Interop;

namespace BasicWinUI
{
    public class App : Application, IXamlMetadataProvider
    {
        private MyWindow m_window;
        private readonly XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider _provider = new();

        public bool Result => m_window?.Result ?? false;

        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (m_window != null)
                return;

            Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new XamlControlsResources());
            m_window = new MyWindow();
            m_window.Activate();
        }

        public IXamlType GetXamlType(Type type) => _provider.GetXamlType(type);
        public IXamlType GetXamlType(string fullName) => _provider.GetXamlType(fullName);
        public XmlnsDefinition[] GetXmlnsDefinitions() =>  _provider.GetXmlnsDefinitions();

        public static bool Run()
        {
            App app = null;
            Bootstrap.Initialize(0x0010005); // asks for WinAppSDK version 1.5, or gets "Package dependency criteria could not be resolved" error
            XamlCheckProcessRequirements();
            Application.Start((p) =>
            {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherQueueSynchronizationContext(DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread()));
                app = new App();
            });
            Bootstrap.Shutdown();
            return app?.Result ?? false;
        }

        [DllImport("microsoft.ui.xaml")]
        private static extern void XamlCheckProcessRequirements();
    }

    public class MyWindow : Window
    {
        public MyWindow()
        {
            Title = "Basic WinUI3";

            // set icon by path
            AppWindow.SetIcon("BasicWinUI.ico");

            // size & center
            var area = DisplayArea.GetFromWindowId(AppWindow.Id, DisplayAreaFallback.Nearest);
            var width = 300; var height = 150;
            var rc = new RectInt32((area.WorkArea.Width - width) / 2, (area.WorkArea.Height - height) / 2, width, height);
            AppWindow.MoveAndResize(rc);

            // give a "dialog" look
            if (AppWindow.Presenter is OverlappedPresenter p)
            {
                p.IsMinimizable = false;
                p.IsMaximizable = false;
                p.IsResizable = false;
            }

            // create the content as a panel
            var panel = new StackPanel { Margin = new Thickness(10) };
            Content = panel;
            panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Are you sure you want to do this?", HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center });

            // create a panel for buttons
            var buttons = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center };
            panel.Children.Add(buttons);

            // add yes & no buttons
            var yes = new Button { Content = "Yes", Margin = new Thickness(10) };
            var no = new Button { Content = "No", Margin = new Thickness(10) };
            buttons.Children.Add(yes);
            buttons.Children.Add(no);

            no.Click += (s, e) => Close();
            yes.Click += async (s, e) =>
            {
                // show some other form
                var dlg = new MessageDialog("You did click yes", Title);
                InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(dlg, WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this));
                await dlg.ShowAsync();
                Result = true;
                Close();
            };

            // focus on first button
            panel.Loaded += (s, e) => panel.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
        }

       public bool Result { get; set; }
     }
}
"@;
 
$ret = [BasicWinUI.App]::Run() # get result (in this sample code it's a boolean)
$ret

I start it with a .bat like this in the BasicWinUI folder:
C:\myPowerShellPath\PowerShell-7.4.2-win-x64\pwsh.exe -File BasicWinUI.ps1 

And here is what you should get (XAML free):

Now if you want simple XAML support, you can load a XAML file dynamically and bind to UI objects manually. For example, if you create a .XAML file like this and name it BasicWinUIWindow.xaml:
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="okButton">OK</Button>
        <Button x:Name="cancelButton">Cancel</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

Place it into the same folder and use a .ps1 like this for example:
Add-Type -Path ".\WinRT.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.Net.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.InteractiveExperiences.Projection.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.WinUI.dll"

$referencedAssemblies = @(
    "System.IO" # for File
    "System.Threading" # for SynchronizationContext
    ".\WinRT.Runtime.dll"
    ".\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll"
    ".\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.Net.dll"
    ".\Microsoft.InteractiveExperiences.Projection.dll"
    ".\Microsoft.WinUI.dll"
)

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $referencedAssemblies -CompilerOptions /nowarn:CS1701 -Language CSharp @"
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.UI.Dispatching;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.XamlTypeInfo;
using Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.DynamicDependency;

namespace BasicWinUI
{
    public class App : Application, IXamlMetadataProvider
    {
        private readonly XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider _provider = new();
        private Window m_window;
        private static bool _ok;

        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (m_window != null)
                return;

            Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new XamlControlsResources());
            var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Bootstrap).Assembly.Location);

            // load XAML file, should be a Window
            m_window = (Window)XamlReader.Load(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(dir, "BasicWinUIWindow.xaml")));
            var sp = (StackPanel)m_window.Content; // we know root is a stack panel, get buttons
            var ok = (Button)sp.FindName("okButton");
            var cancel = (Button)sp.FindName("cancelButton");
            ok.Click += (s, e) => { _ok = true; m_window.Close(); };
            cancel.Click += (s, e) => m_window.Close();
            m_window.Activate();
        }

        public IXamlType GetXamlType(Type type) => _provider.GetXamlType(type);
        public IXamlType GetXamlType(string fullName) => _provider.GetXamlType(fullName);
        public XmlnsDefinition[] GetXmlnsDefinitions() =>  _provider.GetXmlnsDefinitions();

        public static bool Run()
        {
            Bootstrap.Initialize(0x0010005); // asks for WinAppSDK version 1.5, or gets "Package dependency criteria could not be resolved" error
            XamlCheckProcessRequirements();
            Application.Start((p) =>
            {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherQueueSynchronizationContext(DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread()));
                new App();
            });
            Bootstrap.Shutdown();
            return _ok;
        }

        [DllImport("microsoft.ui.xaml")]
        private static extern void XamlCheckProcessRequirements();
    }
}
"@;
 
$ret = [BasicWinUI.App]::Run() # get result (in this sample code it's a boolean)
$ret

Now this is what you'll see:

PS: the .ps1 code will return true if you press OK and false if you press Cancel.

Thank you so much, it worked! I instantly noticed that it automatically changes background theme based on Windows dark/light mode which is so nice! I have a few questions, can I use native PowerShell code now to create UI elements? How can I send events from inside of the C# code in order to capture it outside and run native PowerShell functions or scriptblocks based on that event? like when a button is pressed etc.

I've changed the code a bit, now it returns a boolean (you can change it to whatever you want). As for creating UI Elements, I'm not sure what you exactly mean. If you want to author full .NET component based on XAML (user control, window, page), it won't work in this code sample, unless you create another UI component (.dll) as I mentioned it. Xaml is the issue. But you can instantiate (new) any UI Element or derive from it in C# code above

In terms of familiarity with WPF, often the XAML would be read from a System.Xml.XmlNodeReader object and passed into a Windows.Markup.XamlReader's load method to actually create the XAML Form in a usable PowerShell object. Is there an equivalent here? The goal is to be able to add the XAML inline and then turn that into a PowerShell object. From there we can add events and such as needed.

@nkasco - I've enhanced the answer

@SimonMourier Is there a way for the Run method to return the Window object to the console without activating it yet so that it can be controlled through PowerShell code at that point? Purpose would be for changing a property or adding an event. This would allow us to create the UI with C# but then create actual functionality with PowerShell.
Then at that point a common practice with WPF would be to use the FindName method to retrieve children of the Window once you have that available, thus turning everything into a usable PS object at that point.

Main goal would be to create a PS object of the type Microsoft.UI.XAML.Window called $Window and when ready to display it run $Window.Activate() with pure PS code. It seems like this is very close.

All needed pieces are there, it's more a matter of how to program Powershell to run in the app loop as you must be able to run powershell code inside the OnLaunched method (runspace, pipelines, etc.). That's what I initially asked "Do you want "pure" powershell or is it ok to use embedded C#". Another way is to write a custom Powershell host (a generic one) that would run an external Powershell code, but you wouldn't be running from pwsh
